# RelativeLayout cannot show in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I try to show the bottom-30dp-part of my relativeLayout with a textView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">               
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop= "-20dp"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/refresh_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pull down..."
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/sys_gray"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
<!--(...there are many elements here)-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I write like this, both the RelativeLayout and textView will not show. They both hide outside their parent RelativeLayout. Is there any attributes to let them show a half(not the whole TextView and RelativeLayout) in their parent RelativeLayout?

Comment: You have a single textview. so you can have one single relative layout.

Comment: And you use `android:layout_marginTop= "-20dp"` because?

Comment: @g00dy I want to hide the top half of the textView by 20dp. But I don't know what's the right way.

Comment: What's the height of the `TextView` in `dp` ? Is it a single line all the time ?

Comment: Try using an anchor view centered in the outer relative layout and aligning to that.

Comment: It's just wrap-content. but the height of refresh_layout is 50dp. @g00dy

Comment: It's the first occasion on which I encounter this requirement :) Why don't you try with `android:layout_marginTop= "-20dp"` on the `TextView` and on the first `RelativeLayout` -> `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`?

Comment: I've tried, but nothing changed. The textView still can't show its bottom half. @g00dy

Comment: I'm guessing that this is going to be pulled down, so why don't you put it in a `ScrollView`, just as an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use bellow link code [enter link description here](https://github.com/wdx700/Android-Pull-To-Refresh/blob/master/PullToRefresh/src/com/dmobile/pulltorefresh);

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. However the example changes the height of the top-layout. I'm still interesting in how to change margin_top to finish this Pull-to-Refresh function.